# Get `entity_type_id` by `entity_type_code`

Tags: magento2, eav

As the title, states, **how can I get `entity_type_id` by `entity_type_code` in Magento 2**?

I've looked in the source code, and the only thing I found was `Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup->getEntityTypeId`, however I'm not sure if this method is meant to be used in normal code, since to get the `entity_type_id` for `catalog_product`, my code becomes like this:

```
$entityTypeId = $objectManager
            ->create('Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetup')
            ->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do so you need to use `Magento/Eav/Model/Config` class.

Here's some code using the object manager (it is not recommended, please use dependency injection in your final code)

```
$entityTypeId = $objectManager
            ->create('Magento\Eav\Model\Config')
            ->getEntityType(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE)
            ->getEntityTypeId();
```

Here is an example from a native Magento 2 file: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/app/code/Magento/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/AbstractEav.php#L71